# How to load the datagridview using OOP C#

Tags: c#

I am a beginner at C# and .NET oop concepts. I want to load the datagridview. I don't know how to pass the data. What I tried so far I attached below.

I created a class std

```
public void get()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server =.; initial catalog=testdb; User ID=sa; Password=123");
    string sql = "select * from std";

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

    while ( dr.Read())
    {
        string stname = dr["st_name"].ToString();
        string nicnum = dr["nic"].ToString();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Form: I am getting data like this way

```
 std ss = new std();
 ss.get();

 dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

If I wrote like this way how to pass data into the datagridview columns? I am stuck in this area

Answer (score 1):

It's easier like this:

```
    public void FillGrid()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from std", "server =.; initial catalog=testdb; User ID=sa; Password=123");
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

but if you're going to use such a low level method of database access you should consider adding a DataSet type of file to your project; visual studio will write all this code and more for you with a few mouse clicks, and it makes a good job of creating tables and adapters that are a lot easier to work with

Comment: sir how get the data from the classs and pass into the grid view

Comment: It is done on the last line of the method. Assigning the filled datatable to the grid's DataSource causes the data to appear in the grid. The data should live in the datatable and be accessed there; if you make changes to the datatable the grid will update to show the changes

Comment: i used above code working but i need the oop concepts. i have created class above std.i want load data from the class in to datagridview

Comment: How about rename the method to GetDataTable, and `return dt` on the last line instead, then you can do `dataGridView1.DataSource = GetDataTable()`

Comment: please write the code

Comment: I think it would be very unfair of me to deprive you of a learning opportunity, by doing your entire homework for you. Happy to help out if you get stuck while having a go yourself though!

Answer (score 0):

you have made multiple mistakes. First you read data wirh dataraeader and in every iteration define two `stname` and `nimnum` variables like. So when loop ends variables are destroyed. You have to define data table and read data by dataraeader and and add them to it row by row. Or read by sqldataadapter and read it immediately and pass to datatable object.Finnaly you pass datatable as return object of function. Use this vala as datasource of datagridview  property if I'm not wrong.

Comment: can you write the code sir